# Any windows based IDE to view objective-c code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, windows, ide, editor

I want to be able to browse through the source code of an iPhone application in windows. I do not want to compile and run the code, just need to have some kind of tool that understands the Objective-C code and iPhone application source structure. Something that view the source code as a whole (project-based) and ideally can link different classes and methods. Something more than just a plain editor with code styling and something less than a full feature IDE. Do you suggest any tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most editors will support Objective-C syntax highlighting.  Personally I use VIM or NotePad++.  I would recommend NotePad++ for ease of use.  But as far as I know there is no 'IDE' for Objective-C for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I use jEdit if I need to see the source code in Windows. Pretty much handles all the structure and syntax highlighting of objective C.

EDIT: Its an editor. Not a IDE. But with your needs of just viewing code, I guess it must suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a bit more than just syntax highlighting, GNUStep has an [IDE called PRoject Center](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ProjectCenter_FAQ).  GNUStep can run on Windows, so allegedly Project Center will too.

Comment: I managed to install Project Center on windows, but the problem is I don't know how to use it! It's so different from a typical IDE and seems to have a lot of bugs. To begin with, I don't know how to add files to a project and right click creates a "zombie" window on the screen! This was my experience with Project Center 0.50.

Comment: Sounds pretty bad then.  I did say "allegedly" :-)

Comment: Yeah I know... I got excited in the beginning, but then... :)

Answer (score 1):

Emacs has good syntax and indentation support for Objective-C, for example it can indent the method calls the way Xcode does (based on ':') and there's a Windows version of it available [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/).

Though it's not an IDE, most of the time I use it for Obj-C/GNUstep without much problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) to tag your source code you could use [any editor](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/tools.html) with support for ctags.

It looks like ctags [does not support](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html) Objective-C directly, but it is fairly easy to [add a new language](http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?t=3367) configuration to ctags.